# Composer: How to check minimum requirements of the current composer.json file?

Tags: composer-php

After adding a composer package which needs mongodb 3.0 and because mongodb 3.0 needs php7, finally code after deployment failed on production, I found out my current composer.json configuration needs php7. How can I run a command and find out minimum requirements of my composer.json file? Something like:

```
composer requirements 
# or
composer requirements-dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
composer show --installed --tree
```

Or the shorthand

```
composer show -i -t
```